# Define a function globally in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have some simple jQuery code, and it has a problem. The menu handler function doesn't work at all.

```
var clicked = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $TemplateMenu= $('<p class="paragraph">texxt</p>');
    $('.TemplateMaker').click();
        this.menuhandler();
    });
});
function menuhandler(){         
    if(clicked == false){
        $(this).after($TemplateMenu);
        clicked = true;
    }
    else{
        $TemplateMenu.remove();
        clicked = false;
}
```

For some reason, the function works if I put it directly inside click() like this:

```
    $('.TemplateMaker').click(function(){
        if(clicked == false){
            $(this).after($TemplateMenu);
            clicked = true;
        }
        else{
            $TemplateMenu.remove();
            clicked = false;
        }
    });
});
```

What is wrong with this code? Did I define the function wrong or do I need something special if the function contain jQuery elements?
Thanks for the help :-)

**Edit:**

I edit the code to include your guys suggestions, its stile doesn't seem to work.
code:

```
var clicked = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $TemplateMenu= $('<p class="paragraph">texxt</p><p class="p2">texxt</p>');
    $('.TemplateMaker').click(menuHandler($(this)));
});
function menuHandler(obj){         
    if(clicked == false){
        $(obj).after($TemplateMenu);
        clicked = true;
    }
    else{
        $TemplateMenu.remove();
        clicked = false;
}}
```

I notic now that the jquery throw this "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. ", but I don't know how its contact to my script.

Comment: What makes you think your regular ordinary straight function would be chainable to a native DOM element ?

Comment: Call it using `menuhandler()` and not `this.menuhandler()`.

Comment: so how it will know what is $(this)?

Comment: you could do `menuhandler($(this))` & `function menuhandler(referenced_element){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the menuHandler function to fire when someone clicks on the button? Then you can simply change your code as follows:

```
$('.TemplateMaker').click(menuHandler);
```

**Edit:**
You basically have two options:

**Option1:**

You don't have to pass `$(this)` change your code to this (make sure you remove the parameter in the menuHandler function if you choose this approach):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $TemplateMenu= $('<p class="paragraph">texxt</p><p class="p2">texxt</p>');
    $('.TemplateMaker').click(menuHandler);
});
```

**Option2:**

Or if you want to pass `$(this)` you can do something like this (keep the parameter in the menuHandler function if you choose this approach):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $TemplateMenu= $('<p class="paragraph">texxt</p><p class="p2">texxt</p>');
    $('.TemplateMaker').click(function() {
       menuHandler($(this));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.TemplateMaker').click();
        this.menuhandler();
    });
```

Try replacing **this.menuhandler();**  with just **menuhandler();** as shown below:

```
$('.TemplateMaker').click();
        menuhandler();
    });
```

**Edit:** In response to your comment.  Try using **this** instead of **$(this)** in the menuhandler() of your original code.

Comment: Its not working.
I am not sure it will work because i think its not knowing what is $this anymore.

Comment: Try using **this** instead of **$(this)** in the **menuhandler()** of your original code.

Comment: That will not solve his problem. He wants `menuhandler` to be called when someone clicks on `$('.TemplateMaker')`. He has 2 options, he can pass the `$(this)` reference to the function as a parameter call or just call the function directly inside the `click` handler.